CMake Configuration Error When Integrating Salesforce with React Native Using react-native-screens
I'm working on integrating Salesforce into a React Native application and I've encountered a persistent CMake configuration error when using the react-native-screens library. I'm attempting to set up OAuth authentication with Salesforce and utilize the library to manage screen transitions, but the build process consistently fails during the CMake step. Here's the relevant error output:
> Task :react-native-screens:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ReactAndroid" with
  any of the following names:
    ReactAndroidConfig.cmake
    reactandroid-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "ReactAndroid" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "ReactAndroid_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "ReactAndroid" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.

Details:
React Native Version: 0.70.14
React Native Screens Version: 3.6.0
Development Environment: Windows 10
Build Command: npx react-native run-android
I've tried setting the ReactAndroid_DIR in the CMakeLists.txt file to point to my React Native package directory and checked that the required *.cmake files exist, but the issue persists. Here's the section of my CMakeLists.txt:
find_package(ReactAndroid REQUIRED CONFIG)

I've followed the installation instructions for all related packages and confirmed that other configurations related to React Native and Salesforce integration are correctly set up. Despite this, the build fails specifically at this step. I suspect there might be a missing configuration or a compatibility issue with versions.
Questions:
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with react-native-screens or during any React Native project involving Salesforce?
What are the potential steps to correctly configure CMake for React Native projects on Windows?
Could this be an issue with the specific version of React Native or the react-native-screens package?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
